# Python loop query and issue

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to Python so patience may be required on your behalf :) If this is not the right area for this then please let me know. I'm having trouble with a for loop navigating through a list. The idea here is to print "True" when a consecutive set of numbers are found in the list however it shouldn't print true if the sequence contains less than 3 consecutive iterations.

For example:

Ideally the program would say "You have 3 sequences in your list". In this case it would be (1,2,3), (10,11,12) and (22,23,24). Notice there are 2 other consecutive sets of numbers in the list (7,8) and (15,16) however the program should ignore them because it's less than 3 (as mentioned above). Please find code below however I'm at a slight road block. Appreciate any pointers you may have.

```
list1=[1,2,3,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,22,23,24]

for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    if (list1[i] + 1 == list1[i+1]):
        count+=1
    if count >=3:
        print("True")
    else:
        continue
    continue
print(count)
```

I'm sure I have read the answer in similar posts but I would like to understand the code I'm missing rather than inserting code that doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the query is to have only unique numbers in the sequences .. so below code will just work fine...

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
count=0
i=0
while i < (len(list1)-3):
    if list1[i]+1 == list1[i+1]:
        if list1[i+1]+1 == list1[i+2]:
            print(list1[i], list1[i+1], list1[i+2])
            i=i+2
            count=count+1
    i=i+1

print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. It's good to see it working however what if I wanted to not print out every iteration of  a sequence so for example I don't want it to print this:

Comment: Apologies Sandeep, I had an edit issue while trying to correct my last comment. Please see proper comment as follows:       Thanks Sandeep. It's good to see it working however what if I wanted to not print out every possible sequence so for example if my list was [1,2,3,4,5,6], currently your code above would print: (1,2,3)(2,3,4)(4,5,6). I know if I modify your code slightly it will help but I don't want to repeat every number in each output. I'm trying to get to a place where if the program finds a sequence of 3 numbers it would print (1,2,3) and (4,5,6). Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: thanks a mill, tried your new code. Works perfectly :)

Comment: I spoke to soon :) please see my previous detailed comment. That's the issue I'm facing. If you have any ideas please let me know

Comment: so you want the sequence in the output.. that's what my first code was doing.. just uncomment the first print statement in my code... also do accept the answer if that works....

Comment: your answer above is fine but it will count duplicates. For example if I had a list that contains the following numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] the answer using your above code will be '8'. This is because the loop goes like this (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6),(5,6,7),(6,7,8),(7,8,9),(8,9,10). That's 8 sets in total however I would like the answer to be 3 instead so the loop would go like this (1,2,3), (4,5,6),(7,8,9). Hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26380198)